# Issue aligning fields in a form using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap, I'm creating a registration form with two input fields:

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="user_password">Password</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input type="{{passwordType}}" data-ng-change="passwordChanged();" data-ng-model="user.password"
               class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user_password"
               placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label">Show Password</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="showPassword" data-ng-checked="showPassword"
               data-ng-click="switchPasswordType()">
    </div>

</div>
```

However I don't know what css style I'm missing but the label and the input field appeas one below the other at the left of the grid-container, so no like usual form. I have tried to put both inside a "" with the style="display:inline-block" and still same problem.

Any ideas how to sove that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: float left i often use? match width then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I just created a row with two columns inside one for the label and other for the input and it made the job.

```
 <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label class="control-label" class="" for="user_email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="email" auto-focus autofocus="true" data-ng-model="user.email"
                                       id="user_email" name="user_email"
                                       placeholder="Insert your email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```